# Can we restrict users in identity server4 to specific applications?

Tags: authentication, identity, identityserver4

I am trying to implement IdentityServer 4 for enterprise scenario.

I understand that users are registered against Identity server.

My question is how to give permissions to users against applications, like as users are needed to assign to a particular application, if not assigned application should return unauthorized.

If a user needs to access multiple applications then multiple assignments are needed.

I am looking a way for Identity server to invalidate the submitted token if the user doesn't have access to the application in a single go, even though the challenged token might be valid if it is submitted by other application which the user has access to

Comment: If it is not too late, i would suggest having another table UserClients, If the user is not assigned to a client. Deny the authentication.

Answer (score 19):

Identity Server absolutely handles authorizations on the most basic level. It creates authorization codes and access_tokens that are essential in an applications authorization.  Without them you cannot get authorized.  Thus for others to claim Identity Server does not do authorizations is flat out wrong.

I came in here a week ago looking for a solution for this very same problem.  I want to restrict users to specific applications by not granting them access tokens if they fail to meet certain parameters, in my case a UserClient table.  Lucky for you I have a solution.  Identity Server 4 implements a few, what they call, CustomValidators that occur at the time of authorization or token creation.  They are

```
   internal class DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator : ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
   internal class DefaultCustomTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
   public class DefaultCustomTokenValidator : ICustomTokenValidator
```

There name really says it when they get called.  Each one contains a single method

```
   public Task ValidateAsync(CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext context)
   { 
        return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
```

Notice something?  That's is right! It does nothing.  Almost as if they are meant to be replaced. (It is).

This is the area that you can add your custom logic to reject the request.  CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext contains ClientId and User claim information.  It also contains a boolean value called IsError. Simply set that to true and whamy! Access denied. You can also set error messages etc.  Here is an example that implements the ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator inface that will restrict a user based on there user Id

```
  public Task ValidateAsync(CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Subject.FindFirst("sub");
        if (sub != null && sub.Value != "88421113")
        {
            context.Result.IsError = true;
            context.Result.Error = "Unauthorized";
            context.Result.ErrorDescription = "You are not authorized for this client";
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Feel free to inject a dbcontext or two to read off of your userclient table.  I check the sub claim to be null because this will get hit several times before actual login occurs.

From what I noticed all three behave similar in terms of use, but different in terms of outcome. Setting an error ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator will prevent the redirect to your client and instead direct you to the Identity Server error screen.  The other two will redirect back to the client and generally throw some throw some sort of HttpResponse error. Therefore replacing the ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator seems to work best.

So simply created a class that implements ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator.  Then add that into your identity services like so

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator<MyCustomValidator>()
```

and you are done done.

Comment: too many words words. wish it was half shorter. but take my 10 for the idea anyway : )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will try to keep things shorter.  I was just super exited when I figured this out

Comment: The key words here are 'at the most basic level' but as Scott said (one of the contributors to IdentityServer BTW who probably should know the intent), IdSvr isn't intended for authz decision making - that has to lie with the application. Read this for more information https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/. Sure you can hack in some basic authz (restricting on clientId, for example) but it is wise to appreciate that IdSvr is to authenticate a user. "This user is who they say they are". It has to be the job of something else to decide what that user can do.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider this a hack considering these classes are built specifically to throw errors if you see something that you do not like. The client id is being passed into these methods for a reason, so if I am wrong, maybe scott can further explain the intent of these classes.

@Mashton As far as authentication vs authorization, one cannot work without the other.  IdSrv grants access tokens, to grant access to applications.  These are client specific. If the intent was to only authenticate a user, there would be no reason to have access tokens specific to an individual client.

Comment: The piece you are completely ignoring is that identity server not only tells an application "This user is who they say they are", but it also says "so here is your access token"

Comment: Yes, those classes exist so you can customise request parameter validation at either the token or authorization endpoint - the authorization of *whether this user is who they say they are*. You are free to implement any method you like to define whether the user is who they say they are, and if you allow them then you provide that access token. I'm not sure of any more ways to say that this isn't the same (shouldn't be the same) as application authorization, which should (must) be done by the application unless you want to end up in a world of tangle.

Comment: Your deleted comment likening it to a passport was pretty good actually: a passport states who you are, and is granted by an authority who vouches for you. This is the equivalent of IdSvr and your access token. This passport *doesn't* grant you entry to every country (application) though: the rules of entry for that country are for them to decide, and while some may choose to let you in just because you have a passport from a specific country this is not a universal rule. Others may require specific stamps (claims) on your passport. Others may just laugh and tell you to F-off :)

Comment: IdSrv doesn't do any authorization...  Yet it supplies authorization codes you retrieve from the authorization endpoint, of which passes through the an  authorization request validator.  Check mate.

Comment: You are confusing application access with application authorization.  The two are different.  You cannot access an application if idsrv refuses to acknowledge who you are.  What you think I am suggesting is reaching out to identy everytime an authorization is needed.  That is not what I am suggesting at all.    Say what you will about my post, but I am currently doing this hosting about 5 different application and it works perfect.

Comment: Great answer thanks. This was what I was looking for. Authorization to an application is indeed different to Authorization within an application.  For my use case it's important to distinguish cleanly between internal and external users.  I want to stop external users getting to internal users only SPA application.

Ps. I have an additional Authorization service to deal with what a user can and cannot do within an application.

Comment: I also agree there is a definitive difference between the two types of authorization. Why have your user store centralised but not the user to application mapping. Ive used many IdPs and nearly all of them have some way to store this kind of mapping. However, IdSrv 4 is built to be flexible and extensible and, in particular, is user store agnostic. Which I think is why it doesn't have the concept by default. This answer is sound solution and extension to the base logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a claim in your IdentityServer4's claims table called "role" and in your application, add some UI to authorize a person via email or similar, and then set his/her role in the claims db. And you can also delete the authorized user from your application, which should un-assign a role to that particular person. Thus he/she although is successfully authenticated, can't use your application because you have authorized then. Hope this approach helps you!

Answer (score 1):

For users, IdentityServer is authentication only. Authorization should be handled by your application.

Authentication = Verifying who a user is

Authorization = Verify what a user can do

### Update

I wrote an article on this topic to clarify how OAuth 2.0 does is not user-level authorization. Hope it helps! https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/OAuth-is-Not-User-Authorization

Comment: thanks for the reply, If i am not wrong, Scopes in identity server provide authorization only right? I read that Identity server is implemented on OpenID connect which also has Authorization flows

Comment: Almost. Scopes are what a client application is allowed to request. Not necessarily what the user is allowed to access. App to app permissions are again handled by those apps, you could ask for certain API scopes but this would again be done by the app.

Comment: scott, do you have any better idea on how do we connect the databases of application and identity server to perform authorization against sub or id ? other than user access validation all authorization can be performed by using claims ?

Comment: I guess your application creates its own authorization codes and access tokens?  Identity Server absolutely handles authorizations on the most primitive level.

Comment: Sorry, only just seen this. Authorization codes and access tokens represent the fact that the user authorizes the client application to act on their behalf. This process (OAuth) is delegation. Unfortunately, it does not authorize the user to use the client or protected resource.

Comment: @Scott Brady Really? Then how do you get past an authorize attribute without an access token?

Comment: Yep. An access token just means that the user gave the client app permission to use that API. If the user isn't allowed to use that API, then that's down to the API to police. I highly recommend giving the core OAuth 2.0 specification a read - it's one of the friendlier RFCs to read :)

Comment: @Scott Brady, You didn't anwer my question.  How do you get access a secure client or resource without an access token?

Comment: I know. It was a bit of a loaded question and, based on your prior interaction with @Mashton, I decided not to take the bait. While I would love to teach you OAuth, this is StackOverflow comments and I unfortunately don’t have the time. Dom, Brock, and myself are all available for consultancy via identityserver.com but other than that I’m going to have to leave this thread.

Comment: Here is another "loaded question".  What key do you use for the header when passing an access token created by idsrv4 for accessing a secured endpoint?  Don't bother. The answer is "Authorization".

Comment: Keep in mind this has nothing to do with user data. It is the same for client credentials without user data as it is for authorization code.  IdSrv4 will revoke access to the application if the access token does not pass the smell test. In fact, all of this is done prior to requesting an id token. This sounds like authorization to me.  I think the problem is, in all your arrogance, you failed to realize you were building an authorization software that sits on top of an authentication protocol. Although that is not what was intended, it is how it is used in all practical applications of it.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott says, Identity Server will **authenticate** that the user is who they say they are, not explicitly tell you what that user can do.

You can use the claims returned as part of that authentication to then perform authorization checks within your app. For example, you might use the `sub` or `id` claims to perform checks from your app on whether the user associated with that sub/id is allowed to access a specific resource.

The water gets a bit muddier when you bring `role` claims into the picture, but so long as you appreciate the difference between authentication and authorization you should be ok.

Comment: how do we connect the databases of application and identity server to perform authorization against sub or id ? other than user access validation all authorization can be performed by using claims ?

Comment: It depends on how you are managing your users. In our situation we have an assembly that is our identity provider (using ASP.NET Identity), and this can be accessed by both our identity server (to authenticate and issue tokens) and our application (for creating/editing users, and authorizing access)

Answer (score 0):

In our enterprise scenario we split it into layers:

- We introduced a tenant -- a customer (organization) of our enterprise
  solution.
- Then we have roles (not more than 20 or so) assigned for
  each particular user.

IdentityServer fetches users from tenant and access APIs. The only pre-check it performs is that a particular client (application), requested a token, is not restricted for the particular tenant (customer-level licensing), otherwise we display a message and block the challenge response.

Then we come to an app. With a valid token, having tenant and roles inside. The roles-to-functions assignment could be unique within the tenant. So the application itself performs a granulate permissions check, using a separate API. The application is free to enable-disable some functions or even redirect to the special page in IdSrv "Access denied for the app".

With such approach we are scalable, we are configurable, we are as fast as we want. In previous generation we had "all in one" identity+access+licensing monster-like system, and we decided to split. Today we do not face any real limits with adding new customers (tenants), having 20000 users in average each.

Comment: The whole point is to not have to maintain user data on the client

Comment: @JSON there is an "out of the box" solution, called *MS Identity*, it offers roles+role-claims, all in one jwt, generated at the server.  But it says nothing about invalidation (like any jwt-based approach) and in case of 10+ apps, 50+ function rights for each and 10+K users, it triggers tons of traffic and calculations, so it can't be treated as enterprise. For small apps with 1-2-3 access levels, it must work smoothly.

Comment: but, probably, yes, it could be useful to combine MS Identity with Custom validator in IdSrv and this way restrict some apps dynamically, based on current identity.

Comment: @D_5,  My solution sovles all of that, but I digress

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you can redirect user back to respective client login page it they are not assigned to application/client by using `IProfileService` of `IdentityServer4.Services`

```
public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
{
   if (!string.Equals("MyAllowedApplicationId", context.Client.ClientId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      context.IsActive = false;
   }
 }
```

*You have to set `IsActive = false` to redirect user back to login page where user can login with user details which is allowed in application*